# Sending an Audio file and a Text message to WhatsApp

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent

I want to send a Mp3 file and a text message to any contact on Whatsapp.
While I am able to send either the Mp3 file or the text message I am not able to send them both together.
Here is what I am doing to send a text message :-

```
Intent waIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
waIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
waIntent.setType("text/plain");
waIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(waIntent, "Share with"));
```

and to send a Mp3 file :-

```
Intent waIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
waIntent.setType("audio/*");
waIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
waIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(waIntent, "Share with"));
```

Please suggest a way so that I can send them both.

Comment: I dont think this can be done because you can send only one kind of MIMI-TYPE at a time in the intent. But in your case you will need to send both.

Comment: however you can send multiple Extras to an intent. try sending with mime-type audio and put both `EXTRA_STREAM` and `EXTRA_TEXT` as the extras.. see what happens. :P

Comment: Thanks for replying buddy. I tried doing that. It sends one of them and not both. Is there any way you can suggest so that I can send both using a single Button?

Comment: which one does it sends?

Comment: The one given before. The MIME-TYPE which i set before is sent.

Comment: you mean whatever mime type is set the respective data is sent. it does not matter what extras are set?

Comment: No maybe it does, I've not checked for that. But only one is sent and not both :(

Comment: Is it possible to do it according to you?

Comment: well only if we trick it by putting both extras on a particular MIME-TYPE. if not then I don't think there is another way.

Comment: Okay. No luck so far...